# $post->id vs $post->ID problem after using Wordpress config bootstrap

Tags: wp-config, localhost, local-installation

I'm developing with Wordpress in a multi environment scenario. I develop on my local machine, test on a server and so on.

I was using the "trick" of having a `local-config.php` file to have different configurations based on the environment. Today I discovered this: 
[Wordpress config bootstrap](https://github.com/Abban/WordPress-Config-Bootstrap).

It's just a simple improvement of the default wp-config.php file. It's working fine, but on my local environment appeared this error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in /home/carlo/public_html/altrababele/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/index.php on line 21
```

The code generating the error is this:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->id); ?><div class="date"><time datetime="<?php echo the_time('y-m-j'); ?>" pubdate><?php the_time('j'); ?><br><?php the_time('M'); ?><br><?php the_time('y'); ?></time></div>
```

I set the debug option to `false`, but nothing changes. The problem appears to be that `id` is lowercase, so writing `$post->ID` actually solves the issue. It's strange because if I use the `local-config.php` it works just fine, but all the options are the same.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress-Config-Bootstrap is setting `DEBUG` to `true` on a local installation. If you try to define `DEBUG` again later you should get another error. The solution is not to use the non-existent property `$id`. Notices should be fixed not suppressed.